# Singleton classes containing fields of each other null reference exception

Tags: c#, .net, singleton

In my application I need to have few singleton classes. Each of them has some fields of others singleton classes to use them. Below I reconstructed the issue on simple example:

```
  public sealed class A
{
    private B b = B.Instance;

    private static readonly A instance = new A();
    public static A Instance { get { return instance; } }
    static A() { }
    private A() { }

    public void Do()
    {
        b.ToString();
    }
}

public sealed class B
{
    A a = A.Instance;

    private static readonly B instance = new B();
    public static B Instance { get { return instance; } }
    static B() { }
    private B() { }

    public void Do()
    {
        a.ToString();
    }
}


class Program
{
    static B b = B.Instance;
    static A a = A.Instance;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        b.Do();
        a.Do();
    }
}
```

Null reference exception coming because fields are null. So how can I initialize and use such interconnected singleton classes?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? This kind of cross-dependency is usually a sign of bad design.

Answer (score 0):

The constructors don't run in parallel so when the first is being created the second Singleton has not yet been created.

Instead of setting the property to the value directly you'd likely write something like this in class B:

```
private A AProp {
  get {
    if(a == null)
      a = A.Instance;

    return a;  
  }
}
```

You'd do the same the other way round in class A. So getting the value is delayed until first access and at that time the other Singleton has already been created.

In what scenario exactlly something like this is a good idea is another question. Especially given that instead of accessing it in a local field you could always just access it using A.Instance anyway (so the local field becomes kind of redundant at that point.